# How to change css properties

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create 12 columns using html. I have a css class called `.columnContent` with few properties one of them being background-color: (set to red)

I need to changed the background-color as I want every column to have different colors. How do I change the property of the column class when declaring it in html? Or can I do using div? otherwise I will have to create 12 css classes, there must be a better way of doing it.

I tried `<div style="color"` but that only changes the text color not the background color for the columns.

```css
.columnWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.columnContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: red; /* <- */
}
```

```html
<div id="centerContainer">
  <div class="columnWrapper">
    <div sclass="columnContent">
    </div>
    <div class="columnContent">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assign correct classes. Classes should describe the content, for instance "population" or "scores". Then it's easy to assign different styles to each. On the other hand, if you just want alternating colors unrelated to content, you can use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) or :nth-child. Also, remember you can assign several classes to a single element.

Comment: Careful, little typo on your first div class "collumnContent" : class instead of sclass

Comment: @andreas: Please do not add tags for the sake of filler.

Comment: @BoltClock understood. But at least "css-selectors" should be tagged, since the question is about selecting elements with the same class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo class to apply the different colors to your `.columnContent` elements, i.e.:

```
.columnContent:nth-child(1) { background-color: green; }
.columnContent:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }
.columnContent:nth-child(3) { background-color: blue; }
/* and so on */
```

Here is a working example:

```css
.columnWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.columnContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 3px;
}

.columnContent:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

.columnContent:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.columnContent:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.columnContent:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="centerContainer">
  <div class="columnWrapper">
    <div class="columnContent"></div>
    <div class="columnContent"></div>
    <div class="columnContent"></div>
    <div class="columnContent"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A quick question, can I declare a specific child number such as nth-child(1,3,7)? I tried it but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child like this for trigger a specific column:

```css
.columnWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.columnContent {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 3px;
    **background-color: red;**
}

.columnContent:nth-child(1){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(2){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(3){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(4){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(5){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(6){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(7){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(8){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(9){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(10){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(11){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.columnContent:nth-child(12){
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

```html
<div class="columnWrapper">
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can trigger the first or the last column using first-child and last-child like this :

```css
.columnWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.columnContent{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: red;
}

.columnContent:first-child{
  background-color: blue;
}

.columnContent:last-child{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnWrapper">
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
  <div class="columnContent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine?

Answer (score -1):

You can loop using JavaScript like:

```
<div id="centerContainer">
<div class="columnWrapper">
<script>
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById('columnWrapper').innerHTML='<div class="columnContent' + i + ' "> test </div>';
}
</script>

</div>
</div>
```

Then you style them with CSS differently.

PS: This isn't the best approach for dynamic pages. If you're using a server-side scripting language like `PHP`, you can loop the results in `DIV` before displaying them.